# Sparklyr "NoSuchTableException" error after subsetting data

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparklyr

I am new to `sparklyr` and haven't had any formal training - which will become obvious after this question. I'm also more on the statistician side of the spectrum which isn't helping. I'm getting an error after sub-setting a Spark `DataFrame`.

Consider the following example:

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local[*]")
iris_tbl <- copy_to(sc, iris, name="iris", overwrite=TRUE)

#check column names
colnames(iris_tbl)

#subset so only a few variables remain  
subdf <- iris_tbl %>%
  select(Sepal_Length,Species)

subdf <- spark_dataframe(subdf)

#error happens when I try this operation
spark_session(sc) %>% 
  invoke("table", "subdf")
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchTableException
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientInterface$$anonfun$getTable$1.apply(ClientInterface.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientInterface$$anonfun$getTable$1.apply(ClientInterface.scala:122)
```

There are several other lines of the error.

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. "subdf" is a Spark `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand why this doesn't work you have to understand what happens when you `copy_to`. Internally `sparklyr` will register temporary table using Spark metastore and treat it more or less like just another database. This is why:

```
spark_session(sc) %>% invoke("table", "iris")
```

can find the "iris" table:

```
<jobj[32]>
  class org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
  [Sepal_Length: double, Sepal_Width: double ... 3 more fields]
```

`subdf` from the other hand is just plain local object. It is not registered in the metastore hence it cannot be accessed using Spark catalog. To make it work you can register Spark `DataFrame`:

```
subdf <- iris_tbl %>% 
  select(Sepal_Length, Species)

spark_dataframe(subdf) %>%
  invoke("createOrReplaceTempView", "subdf")
```

or `copy_to` if data is small enough to be handled by the driver:

```
subdf <- iris_tbl %>% 
  select(Sepal_Length, Species) %>% 
  copy_to(sc, ., name="subdf", overwrite=TRUE)
```

If you work with Spark 1.x `createOrReplaceTempView` should be replaced with `registerTempTable`.